# What is the cause of inclination in fluid in ground frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

we know in frame of container. due to pseudo force+ mg's resultant the fluid gets inclined in back direction but when viewed from ground frame there is no pseudo force and rather the net acceleration is right then what causes this inclination in back direction in the fluid please draw proper FBD also..[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each fluid particle at the surface, there is a net hydrostatic pressure from the "fluid-hill" behind. This pressure acts as the desired accelerating force to move the fluid particles or the whole fluid.